# GAE throws AccessControlException by TimedSemaphore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-commons-lang

I'm using Google App Engine (Java) and my war has to use [TimedSemaphore](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/TimedSemaphore.html) to control resources within specific time period but GAE throws well-known exceptions due to accessed to disallowed API as follows.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:389)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:674)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:613)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:925)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1587)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.TimedSemaphore.startTimer(TimedSemaphore.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.TimedSemaphore.acquire(TimedSemaphore.java:300)
```

However, as far as my understanding, [The JRE Class White List](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) contains all of classes called by TimedSemaphore.

My billing status is of course already active in order to use all features of GAE. Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I realized we can't invoke `new Thread()` on GAE. It's described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox). I have to look for the workaround.. Okay.

Comment: We can define `new TimedSemaphore(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 4800)` and above exception will gone but it doesn't work due to limitations of GAE.